# how do I upload a file to the server in the folder uploads in yii basic. I have tried but its npt working

Tags: php, yii2

Its not uploading the file the folder in the project.

How can I upload the file?

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new UploadForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $filename=$model->filename;
            $model->file= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
            $model->file->saveAs('uploads/' .$filename.'.'.$model->file->extension );
```

Comment: Do you face any error or not?

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an attribute to store the file name in the model class. Also declare a file validation rule for this attribute to ensure a file is uploaded with specific extension name.

Then, in the controller class define an action method to collect user-submitted data.

```
    $model = new UploadForm();
    if(isset(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        $model->attributes=Yii::$app->request->post();
        $model->file=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
        if($model->save())
        {
            $model->file->saveAs('path/to/localFile');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Class 'app\controllers\CUploadedFile' not found

Answer (score 1):

It is not uploading, because you are calling `$model->save()` before adding a `value` to the `$model->file` field.

The code should look like

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $filename = $model->ltkcnt_contracts_name;
    $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
    if ($model->save()) {
        $model->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $filename . '.' . $model->file->extension);
    }
}
```

You should read [this article](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model) for more info.

Comment: you realize that the code doesnt reach the if statement at ```if ($model->save()) {
        $model->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $filename . '.' . $model->file->extension);
    }``` when i exit() beforethe  if statement at $model->save it  works, but when i exit inside the if statement, after model->save , the exit  doesnt work at all

Comment: @rabin254 This is because, some of the validation fails. Try running `$model->save(false);` instead. If it works now, you should read the validation rules.

Comment: This is the error am getting if i set save(false)  Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException "file cannot be null"

Comment: @rabin254 can you do a `var_dump(UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file'))` before the save and give me the result? If the result is big, edit the answer and dump it there.

Comment: it does nothing at all behaves as it was before

Comment: @rabin254 I need the result from that `var_dump` Add a `die;` after the var_dump and give me the result it gives.

Comment: This is the result NULL

Comment: @rabin254 can you show me the code of `UploadForm()`. Paste it in the question. Also, have you read [this article](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload)?

Comment: ```<?php

namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class Contracts extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    
     public $file;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'uploads_table';
    }

    
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            
            [['file'], 'file'],
            
        ];
    }

    
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
          
            'file' => 'Files',
        ];
    }

  }```

Comment: Look at it below

Comment: @rabin254 I saw it, but this is the `Contracts` model, I need to look at the `UploadForm()` model, as it is the one you are calling.

Comment: Can I set the path of the file in the model table

Comment: @rabin254 You can rewrite the model `afterSave()` function to run the code instead.

Comment: Am not getting what you meam please?

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class Contracts extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

     public $file;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'uploads_table';
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            [['file'], 'file'],

        ];
    }


    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [

            'file' => 'Files',
        ];
    }

}
```